# how do i work around 429 errors in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I run into 429 errors a lot in selenium, because the driver is too fast for the server. this causes the website to get stuck (with no error message presented to the user). I use waits and I've tried using the sleep method but it doesn't always work. Is there anything I can do or is this a design flaw on the website - shouldn't the error be presented to the user so I can try to reload the page?

I am using incognito mode so cookies aren't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the bellow line of code after declaring the driver

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

also using sleep having assigned it a fair amount of time? make sure that it's using millescondes

```
thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: what does that first line do? 
i have tried adding thread.sleep but it isnt a good solution because the issue happens very randomly.

Comment: This timeout is used to specify the amount of time the driver should wait while searching for an element if it is not immediately present.

Comment: how does that solve my issue?

Comment: i am using webdriverwait for all of my elements, doesn't this do the same thing

Comment: yes basically do the same thing, but can you check the other solution?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue that has to be handled in the source code of the application. I would do the following:

1. Run a performance test and see if I can replicate it.
2. Check the logs of the application to see if this happening frequently on production.

Please see following article for dev to handle 429 errors --> [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429#:%7E:text=The%20HTTP%20429%20Too%20Many,before%20making%20a%20new%20request.)

Otherwise the solution provided by @hamza belatra should be sufficient.

Unless it is a problem in your Test Architecture code, how to the driver is handled and so on.